# Rails form keeps returning a nomethoderror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nomethoderror

```
        <%= form_for rating_ballot, :html => { :class => 'rating_ballot' } do |f| %>
            <%= f.label("value_1", content_tag(:span, '1'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"1"})
            radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 1, current_user_rating == 1, :class => 'rating_button') %>
            <%= f.label("value_2", content_tag(:span, '2'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"2"})
            radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 2, current_user_rating == 2, :class => 'rating_button') %>
            <%= f.label("value_3", content_tag(:span, '3'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"3"})
            radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 3, current_user_rating == 3, :class => 'rating_button') %>
            <%= f.label("value_4", content_tag(:span, '4'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"4"})
            radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 4, current_user_rating == 4, :class => 'rating_button') %>
            <%= f.label("value_5", content_tag(:span, '5'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"5"})
            radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 5, current_user_rating == 5, :class => 'rating_button') %>

            <%= hidden_field_tag("message", msg.message) %>
            <%= f.submit :Submit %>
        <%- end -%>
```

This is my form, I'm trying to create a system for users to rank messages in a "star" system form [this](http://eighty-b.tumblr.com/post/1569674815/creating-an-ajaxified-star-rating-system-in-rails-3) tutorial. I have followed all the instructions on the tutorial but when I include this form I get a nomethoderror `undefined method 'ratings_path'`. In my home_helper I have

```
  def rating_ballot
    if @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_id(params[:msg])
      @rating
    else
      current_user.ratings.new
    end
  end

  def current_user_rating
    if @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_id(params[:msg])
      @rating.value
    else
      "N/A"
    end
  end
```

Why am I getting this error? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a routing problem. *_path are known as path helpers. Run `rake routes` to see what routes you have. You'll likely need to add new routes for your actions in order to use the path helpers. From your code, I'm guessing you'll need:

> resources :ratings

But it's anyones guess what the rest of your application looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that didn't work, What other code should I post so that I can get help with this problem? Thanks

Comment: It looks like in your *helper* you're initializing your action? You might want to go back to the drawing board and look up some MVC resources. Otherwise, I'd prefer to see your *controller* rather than the *helper*.

Comment: I dont have any code related to the rating_ballot in my home_controller

Comment: What does `rake routes` return? Do you have a `rating` model? It looks like the helper is just returning a rating.

Comment: OK, I solved it by doing `resources :ratings` instead of `resources :rating_ballot`. Thanks for your help.